# Eclipse Kepler XDebug to debug Web application. Breakpoints are being ignored

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, debugging, xdebug

My goal is to use Eclipse to debug Wordpress. To start off with, I installed WAMP and Wordpress under WAMP. Then, I created a test program for debugging purposes called : testmeout.php. The name of the wordpress project is insr. To access testmeout.php, I would do:

```
http://localhost:4444/insr/testmeout.php.
```

Below I have noted videos to better explain what I mean. If one looks at this video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyZs6u4qXfs
```

one can see that the option of Run -> Debug Configurations -> PHP CLI Application
** works *** the debugger stops on the breakpoints.

If one looks at this video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1b5bx7iTI2w
```

one can see that the option of Run -> Debug Configurations -> PHP Web Application
*** does not work ***

The breakpoints are blown by and totally ignored.

What am I missing here? Can someone help me out with this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Is the xDebug running on your local server?
phpinfo() report it as a loaded extension?

And if it is running, it will appear like below in
Eclipse, Window->Preference->PHP->Debug->Installed Debuggers.

Debugger type   |   Port
Zend Debugger   |   10000
XDebug          |    9000

My environment just for your reference:
Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
Eclipse Workspace : /XAMPP INSTALL PATH/htdocs
XAMPP v3.2.1
PHP Version 5.5.6